# Has "Unit Test Bundles" on iOS or Mac been an attack vector?

Tags: code-signing, xcode

In the current beta version of XCode, for the first time, you are required to sign your "Unit Test Bundle".
Current beta version being 8.0.

I was wondering if this is a bug that they will fix, or the test bundles have been used for unintended or malicious purposes in the past and now Apple is catching up?